# File opening twice in different tabs in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Im having this problem where i have the same file opened twice in two tabs.
If i open the file from the project explorer i get a tab with this path:

```
ppr3common\ppr3common\library\imovo\imovogeneral.py
```

If i do CTRL+CLICK in a function that is located in this file i get a tab with this path:

```
\Projects\ppr3\ppr3common\ppr3common\library\imovo\imovogeneral.py
```

Is there any way to avoid this and don't have the same file opened twice?
I tried with "workbench.editor.revealIfOpen": true but this doesn't solve my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, try to update but i solved it by reinstall. Log-in with github if you want to keep settings and extensions.

Answer (score 0):

As you see the tab is pinned-up. And also open the tab by right-clicking the file and opening it right.
Go to settings and shortcut keys then check the

> CTRL + SHIFT + 5

for split right in VS Code.